# What is the difference between "dysregulation" and "deregulation" of miRNA?

Tags: terminology, gene-expression, gene-regulation, microrna

I've started to study the role of miRNA in cancer. Wikipedia says:

> Just as miRNA is involved in the normal functioning of eukaryotic
>   cells, so has **dysregulation** of miRNA been associated with disease.
>
> The first human disease known to be associated with miRNA **deregulation**
>   was chronic lymphocytic leukemia.

1- What is the difference between **dysregulation** and **deregulation**?

2- How are these concepts related to **RNA degradation**?

Comment: This is not a homework question but a badly researched. These questions should not be closed as homework (as this is misuse of this reason), but downvoted + commented. The downvotes can be reversed if the question is edited.

Comment: Here at biology we expect people who ask questions to do some research by themselves. What have you found out?

Comment: @Chris — I appreciate your good intentions acting as moderator here. However, the ‘close category, ‘homework’, clearly includes “A question that addresses a basic biology concept that may seem trivial to biology professionals”. (And there is a review category allowing one to vote to close “Low quality posts”.) I have [posted on meta](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/redesigning-biology-stack-exchange-extended/3657#3657) about this being unsatisfactory, and feel that discussion — on meta — is required (as a separate question) on how to resolve this unsatisfactory situation.